# I have used 16x2LCD and renesasRl78/G microcontroller and i am able to display output only once,,how can i make scrolling of lcd to multiple screen?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "iodefine.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "config.h"
#include "system.h"
#include "sfr.h"
#include "lcd_con.h"

extern unsigned char TITL0[32] = "DISPLAYtest 2021";
extern unsigned char TITL1[32] = ">Welcome>Home";
extern unsigned char TITL0[32] = "DISPLAYtest 2020";
extern unsigned char TITL1[32] = ">Welcome>EARTH";
extern unsigned char TITL0[32] = "DISPLAYtest 2023";
extern unsigned char TITL1[32] = ">Welcome>EARTh";

void dispset_titl(void) {

  unsigned char n;
  unsigned char dsp_buf;

  lcd_l1(0x00);
  for (n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
    dsp_buf = TITL0[n]; // line 1
    lcd_dout(dsp_buf);  // 1data write
  }

  lcd_l2(0x40);
  for (n = 0; n < 16; n++) {
    dsp_buf = TITL1[n]; // line 2
    lcd_dout(dsp_buf);  // 1data write
  }
}

void dispset_count(void) {

  delay_msec(100);
  dpcnt[0]++;
  if (dpcnt[0] > 9) {
    dpcnt[0] = 0;
    dpcnt[1]++;
  }
  if (dpcnt[1] > 9) {
    dpcnt[1] = 0;
    dpcnt[2]++;
  }
  if (dpcnt[2] > 9) {
    dpcnt[2] = 0;
    dpcnt[3]++;
  }
  if (dpcnt[3] > 9) {
    dpcnt[3] = 0;
  }
  lcd_cout(0x8C);
  lcd_dout(dpcnt[3] + 0x30);
  lcd_dout(dpcnt[2] + 0x30);
  lcd_dout(dpcnt[1] + 0x30);
  lcd_dout(dpcnt[0] + 0x30);
}

void lcd_init(void) {

  P0 = 0x00; // E=0,R/W=0

  P2 = 0x03;
  P0 = 0x02; // E=1,R/W=0
  delay_micro(100);
  P0 = 0x00; // E=0,R/W=0
  delay_msec(5);

  P2 = 0x03;
  P0 = 0x02; // E=1,R/W=0
  delay_micro(100);
  P0 = 0x00; // E=0,R/W=0
  delay_msec(5);

  P2 = 0x03;
  P0 = 0x02; // E=1,R/W=0
  delay_micro(100);
  P0 = 0x00; // E=0,R/W=0
  delay_msec(5);

  P2 = 0x02;
  P0 = 0x02; // E=1,R/W=0
  delay_micro(100);
  P0 = 0x00; // E=0,R/W=0
  delay_msec(5);

  lcd_cout(0x28); // for 4-bit lcd intialization
  delay_msec(5);
  lcd_cout(0x0F);
  delay_msec(5);
  lcd_cout(0x06);
  delay_msec(5);
  lcd_cout(0x01);
  delay_msec(5);
  lcd_cout(0x02);
  delay_msec(5);
}

void lcd_l1(unsigned char column) {

  unsigned char pos;

  pos = column & 0x0F;
  pos = pos | 0x80;
  lcd_cout(pos);
  delay_msec(5);
}

void lcd_l2(unsigned char column) {

  unsigned char pos;

  pos = column & 0x4F;
  pos = pos | 0xC0;
  lcd_cout(pos);
  delay_msec(5);
}

void lcd_cout(unsigned char code) {

  unsigned char code_msb, code_lsb;

  code_msb = code / 0x10;
  code_lsb = code & 0x0F;
  P0 = 0x00; // E=0,R/W=0

  P2 = code_msb;
  P0 = 0x02; // E=1,R/W=0
  delay_micro(2);
  P0 = 0x00; // E=0,R/W=0

  delay_micro(2);

  P2 = code_lsb;
  P0 = 0x02; // E=1,R/W=0
  delay_micro(2);
  P0 = 0x00; // E=0,R/W=0
  delay_micro(50);
}

void lcd_dout(unsigned char code) {

  unsigned char code_msb, code_lsb;

  code_msb = code / 0x10;
  code_lsb = code & 0x0F;

  P0 = 0x01; // E=0,R/W=1

  P2 = code_msb;
  P0 = 0x03; // E=1,R/W=1
  delay_micro(2);
  P0 = 0x01; // E=0,R/W=1

  delay_micro(2);

  P2 = code_lsb;
  P0 = 0x03; // E=1,R/W=1
  delay_micro(2);
  P0 = 0x01; // E=0,R/W=1
  delay_micro(50);
}

void delay_micro(unsigned int icnt) {

  unsigned int del_cnt;
  for (del_cnt = 0; del_cnt < icnt; del_cnt++) {
    NOP();
    NOP();
    NOP();
    NOP();
    NOP();
  }
}

void delay_msec(unsigned int icnt) {

  unsigned int del_cnt;
  for (del_cnt = 0; del_cnt < icnt; del_cnt++) {
    delay_micro(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: The 16x2 LCD will scroll left/right (reading the characters in DDRAM), but for scrolling up/down, you will need to clear and write each new line to the display. Your DDRAM  buffer for the display is 80 characters. (essentially 40 per-line) so you get 2.5 screens of text for left/right scroll/swap without changing the DDRAM, but for up.down, you need to change the characters in the buffer (DDRAM).

Comment: How to change the character in the buffer (DDRAM)? Would you please assist me regarding this concern!!!!  Thank you

Comment: Your display will use the [HD44780U Controller](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf). The datasheet, while a bit cryptic if you are new to datasheets, explains how you interact with the DDRAM (the characters you write to the controller for display). The LCD has tso basic modes 'command' (where you tell the LCD what to do next (e.g. clear, move cursor position, write character, scroll, etc..) and 'data' where you are sending the characters to the display. The library you use will hide most details from you, but should have basic commands.

Comment: If you notice, your `lcd_l1(0x00)` and `lcd_l2(0x40)` are the display commands for line 1 and 2. Note the addresses `0x00` this is the start of the 40-character buffer that can be displayed for line 1 (e.g. chars 0-15, then 16-32 and 33-40 with 0-8 wrapping around. The line 2 start address is `0x40` and behaves the same way. I find it easier to simply use `char TITL[80] = "both full lines together...";` and then simply shift the display left by 16 to show the next set of lines, etc... You can have multiple 80-char arrays, the LCD can clear/write fairly fast.

Comment: thank you for the information @DavidC.Rankin but i want to print the character of each first and second line with some new character in first and second line in every 5 seconds..how it can be done?

Comment: I don't use Renesas, but here is the [Renesas Liquid Crystal Display (LiquidCrystal Class)](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/gadget-renesas/reference/gr-sakura/library-liquid) To shift every 5 seconds, just fill your 80-char buffer with the first 2 sets of Line1/LIne2 you want, wait 5 seconds, shift to the left 16 chars to display the next lines. Then have the next 80-char buffer ready, at the end of 5 seconds display it -- it will display the 1st 16 chars for Line1/2, wait 5 secs, shift to left by 16, repeat.

Comment: In this turorial of Renesas "Liquid Crystal Display (LiquidCrystal Class)" the Arduino board is required and i am not using arduino board.

Comment: The key is this. Every board will have a different pinout. The library just takes commands from whatever pins your board uses (you look to be using a serial interface in 4-bit mode). If you have been able to display anything at all, you have already got a connection and the library working. Find the command to clear and write a new set of lines exactly the same way you wrote the first. For efficiency, you want to use the full buffer the LCD provides that will give you 4-lines (2 lines x 2) you can display.

Comment: I can find the command 0x01 to clear the entire contents the but when i try to write the new line its not working as i wrote the first.

Comment: `lcd_cout(0x01);` should clear the display if I'm reading your code correctly. (e.g. lcd_command-out 1)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you,now writing to the new line got fine ,next i want to know is how to make cursor pointed to the one position 0x00 with blinking on that position and move that cursor to the positon 0x08 after some delay. –

Comment: If you look at the manual the `Cursor or display shift` command is what you want.. You see the value required as being `"0 0 0 0 1 S/C R/L -- --"`. The command says you want bit-4 as `1`, Shift/Cursor (`S/C`) of `0` (cursor) and Right/Left (`R/L`) of `1` (right) and `--` means it doesn't matter what is in bit-0 or bit-1 positions, those bits are ignored.  So your command value in binary is `b10100` or just `0x14` to move the cursor one position to the right. So do `n = 8; while (n--) lcd_cout(0x14);` to loop 8 times moving the cursor right. (do home first) `lcd_cout(0x2);`

Comment: and how to blink the cursor pointed position?

Comment: Manual again, command `0 0 0 0 0 0 1 D C B` where `D` Display On/Off (`1`), `C` Cursor On/Off (`1`) and `B` Blink On/Off `1`. So your command is binary `b1111` or simply `0xf`. `lcd_cout (0xf);` to turn cursor on blink on, and `b1100` or `0xc` for cursor off blink off, `lcd_cout (0xc);`.

Comment: cann`t i use like this?                                                                                                                 void LCD_Set_Cursor(unsigned char r, unsigned char c)
{
  unsigned char Temp,Low4,High4;
  if(r == 1) 
  {
    Temp = 0x80 + c - 1;                   
    High4 = Temp >> 4;
    Low4 = Temp & 0x0F;
    lcd_cout(High4);
    lcd_cout(Low4);
  }
  if(r == 2) 
  {
    Temp = 0xC0 + c - 1;
    High4 = Temp >> 4;
    Low4 = Temp & 0x0F;
    lcd_cout(High4);
    lcd_cout(Low4);
  }
}

Comment: Usually what is done in your library header file is to define the command, e.g. `LCD_CMD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT  14`, and `LCD_CMD_DISPLAY_ON_CURSOR_BLINK  0f` and `LCD_CMD_DISPLAY_ON_CURSOR_OFF  0c`, etc... That way you would have `lcd_cout (LCD_CMD_DISPLAY_ON_CURSOR_BLINK;`,  etc..for each command you need.  All of the commands are explained on Page 24-26 of the manual. Like I said to begin, it's a bit cryptic at first, but once you make friends with it, the mystery of the display evaporates. It takes a while to digest, so don't feel bad that it's not making sense yet.

Comment: Your `lcd_cout()` command already encapsulates splitting the byte into High/Low 4-bit mode. Your `lcd_dout()` does the same thing for data. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: oh i got it now, and you are talking about  HD44780U Controller mannual or something else from where i can get idea of cursor or display shift ?would you mention me any mannual to refer through it,thanks alot .

Comment: [HD44780U datasheet.pdf](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/HD44780.pdf) -- it will take going over a few time (probably took me a dozen), but then it will just make sense. It really is the key to understanding the LCD.

Comment: As code mention below,i got the cursor and blink on the second line(0x40) of the lcd but along with it i want to shift cursor to the 0x48 address with shifting value present on that address. how can i shift along with value?                             
       { 
        unsigned char n;
        unsigned char dsp_buf;        
        n=8;
      while(n--){ 
      lcd_cout(0x02);
      lcd_cout(0x14);
      lcd_cout(0x0F); 
 
      lcd_l2(0x40);    
      for (n=0 ;n<16 ;n++) {
      dsp_buf = TITL1[n];  //line 2
      lcd_dout(dsp_buf);  //1data write   
       }  
 }}

Comment: To explicitly move the cursor to address `0x48`, you use the "Set DDRAM Address"  The command is `1 ADD ADD ADD ADD ADD ADD ADD`. The bit to invoke the command is `0x80` (bit-7). The address you want is `0x48` so the complete command is `0x80 | 0x48 = 0xC0`. So `lcd_cout (0xC0);` You can write a function as `void set_cursor_pos (uint_fast8_t row, uint_fast8_t col) { if (row) { col |= 0x40; } col |= 0x80; lcd_cout (col); }`

Comment: writing this function did not give me the solution.                                                                  0xC0 is the postion of the starting of second line ,but the cursor i want to move is on 0xC8 and shift the value from 0xC0 to 0xC8;

Comment: Did you use the function to move to `set_cursor_pos (1, 8);` for the 2nd row- 8th position (e.g. address `0x48`)?

Comment: when i run the program it didnot get shifted to that position(0x48).                                  i edited cote as :                                                                                                                        
 void set_cursor_pos (uint_fast8_t row, uint_fast8_t col) 
        {
    set_cursor_pos (1, 8);
    if (row)
                  {
               col |= 0x40;
        } 
        col |= 0x80;
        lcd_cout (col);            
        }

Comment: No, no, no. the function is `void set_cursor_pos (uint_fast8_t row, uint_fast8_t col) { if (row) { col |= 0x40; } col |= 0x80; lcd_cout (col); }` and you set the position to the 2nd line (`row = 1`) and 9th column (`col = 8`) by calling the function where every you need it as `set_cursor_pos (1, 8);` The function *definition* must be (or have a prototype) above the line in the code where you call it. That is the exact command I use daily.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you brother for providing the instruction,finally i got the solution of blinking and shifting after 1 day of rush.